# Trying to get property of non-object when send Email with mailgun

Tags: php, laravel

i'm doing send email with mailgun but get trouble. Here my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\TestMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function mail()
    {
        $user = User::find(1)->toArray();
        Mail::send('emails.active', $user, function($message) use ($user) {
            $message->to($user->email);
            $message->subject('Mailgun Testing');
        });
        dd('Mail Send Successfully');
    }
}
```

here my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox3ae9e61e75da41cab7a649e0f06ac340.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxe90fdef17344b3505ab04d369xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and here my route

```
Route::get('/sendmail','EmailController@mail');
```

and i get trouble is Trying to get property of non-object EmailController.php line 29 ( $message->to($user->email); ) somebody help me and thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line if you are converting it `toArray();`

```
$message->to($user->email);
```

to

```
$message->to($user['email']);
```

Comment: that you need to check in mail gun documentation, or you need to manually move the mail from updates to inbox for the first time and from next time it will come to inbox, that depends totally on the mail server bro]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting to array in line ?

```
        $user = User::find(1)->toArray();
```

`toArray()` converts `$user` to associative array. Just change this line to  following

```
    $user = User::find(1);
```

or following line

```
        $message->to($user->email);
```

to

```
        $message->to($user['email']);
```

Comment: Okay, great and congrats

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mail = \Mail::send('emails.active', array('receiver'=>$user,'sender'=>$sender), 
        function($message) use ($user)
            {

                $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Reset Password!');

            });
```

Pass user parameter inside an array as second parameter in Mail::send()